# Event fired when bottom sheet is active or hidden - Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify for creating my SPA. While using bottomsheet component for my app, I stumbled on a situation where i want fire an event when bottomsheet is hidden.
How do I fire an event when bottomsheet is hidden with another better approach?

My approach using vue `watch`:

```
<v-bottom-sheet v-model="sheet">
          <v-sheet class="text-center" height="50vh" tile>

          </v-sheet>
        </v-bottom-sheet>



new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            sheet: false,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        sheet: function () {
            if (this.sheet == false) {
               alert("Bottom sheet closed");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> **try it**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            sheet: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        sheetComputed:{
          get(){
            if (this.sheet == false) {
               alert("Bottom sheet closed");
            }
            return this.sheet
          },
          set(value){
            this.sheet = value
          }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<v-bottom-sheet v-model="sheetComputed">
   <v-sheet class="text-center" height="50vh" tile>

   </v-sheet>
</v-bottom-sheet>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, if you see the source for [v-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBottomSheet/VBottomSheet.ts). It extends the events from v-dialog, you can use `@input`, `@keydown` or `@click:outside`

`@input` could work for you, but only fires when is active:

```
<v-bottom-sheet v-model="sheet" @input="onInput">
   <v-sheet class="text-center" height="50vh" tile>

   </v-sheet>
</v-bottom-sheet>



new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            sheet: false,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        sheet: function () {
            if (this.sheet == false) {
               alert("Bottom sheet closed");
            }
        }
    },

    methods:{
      onInput(val){
        console.log('v-model change to', val)
      }
    }
})
```

If you want to check both activation and deactivation, `watch` is the only approach.